# Hyperbolic inverse Function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, hyperbolic-functions

[image]

how to find the inverse function of the arcsinh x also the domainof arcsinh

Comment: If arcsinh is the inverse of sinh, then sinh is the inverse of arcsinh.  The domain of arcsinh is the range of sinh.  What's the range of sinh?

Answer (score 2):

suppose 
$$
\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}=y
$$
Then
$$
e^{x}-e^{-x}=2y \Leftrightarrow e^{2x}-2ye^x-1=0
$$
And $\Delta=4\left(y^2+1\right) \geq 0$ then with $X=e^x$
$$
X= \frac{2y \pm \sqrt{4\left(y^2+1\right)}}{2}=y\pm \sqrt{y^2+1}
$$
Then the solution is the positive one ( I let you think about that ) so
$$ 
e^x=y+ \sqrt{y^2+1}
$$
Finally

> $$
> x=\ln\left(y+ \sqrt{y^2+1}\right)
> $$

But you could reverse the thing and evaluate $\text{arcsinh}\left(\text{sinh}\left(x\right)\right)$ to show it is identity.